# Valgrind cross compile for arm 32 bit board - orange pi

Tags: arm, cross-compiling, valgrind, orange-pi

> Q. How to cross compile valgrind for ARM on x86 ubuntu machine ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a self-contained procedure, assuming you are building on a x86_64 Ubuntu Linux machine. If this is not the case, just install the cross-compiler for the `arm-none-linux-gnueabihf` target available from your Linux distribution, make sure it is in your path, and modify the `configure`  command accordingly.

On the PC side:

```
# downloading/installing toolchain
wget https://developer.arm.com/-/media/Files/downloads/gnu-a/10.2-2020.11/binrel/gcc-arm-10.2-2020.11-x86_64-arm-none-linux-gnueabihf.tar.xz?revision=d0b90559-3960-4e4b-9297-7ddbc3e52783&la=en&hash=985078B758BC782BC338DB947347107FBCF8EF6B

sudo mkdir -p /opt/arm/10
sudo tar Jxf gcc-arm-10.2-2020.11-x86_64-arm-none-linux-gnueabihf.tar.xz -C /opt/arm/10

# downloading/extracting valgrind
wget https://sourceware.org/pub/valgrind/valgrind-3.16.1.tar.bz2
tar jxf valgrind-3.16.1.tar.bz2

# building
export PATH=/opt/arm/10/gcc-arm-10.2-2020.11-x86_64-arm-none-linux-gnueabihf/bin:$PATH
mdkir valgrind
cd valgrind

../valgrind-3.16.1/configure --host=arm-none-linux-gnueabihf --prefix=$(pwd)/valgrind-3.16.1-arm-none-linux-gnueabihf
make all install
```

On the Orangepi:

Copy the content of the `valgrind-3.16.1-arm-none-linux-gnueabihf` directory and its sub-directories from your PC into the /usr/local directory of your Orangepi.

Install `libc6-dbg` (assuming you are running Ubuntu or Debian on your Orangepi): `apt-get install libc6-dbg`

test using the procedure provide [here](http://cs.ecs.baylor.edu/%7Edonahoo/tools/valgrind/):

```
wget http://cs.ecs.baylor.edu/~donahoo/tools/valgrind/test.c
gcc -o test -g test.c

valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=yes --show-reachable=yes --num-callers=20 --track-fds=yes ./test
    ==2034== Memcheck, a memory error detector
    ==2034== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
    ==2034== Using Valgrind-3.16.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
    ==2034== Command: ./test
    ==2034==
    ==2034==
    ==2034== FILE DESCRIPTORS: 3 open at exit.
    ==2034== Open file descriptor 2: /dev/ttyS0
    ==2034==    <inherited from parent>
    ==2034==
    ==2034== Open file descriptor 1: /dev/ttyS0
    ==2034==    <inherited from parent>
    ==2034==
    ==2034== Open file descriptor 0: /dev/ttyS0
    ==2034==    <inherited from parent>
    ==2034==
    ==2034==
    ==2034== HEAP SUMMARY:
    ==2034==     in use at exit: 35 bytes in 2 blocks
    ==2034==   total heap usage: 3 allocs, 1 frees, 47 bytes allocated
    ==2034==
    ==2034== 16 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 2
    ==2034==    at 0x484A4B0: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:307)
    ==2034==    by 0x1087DB: main (test.c:15)
    ==2034==
    ==2034== 19 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 2 of 2
    ==2034==    at 0x484A4B0: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:307)
    ==2034==    by 0x1087BB: main (test.c:8)
    ==2034==
    ==2034== LEAK SUMMARY:
    ==2034==    definitely lost: 35 bytes in 2 blocks
    ==2034==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
    ==2034==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
    ==2034==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
```

Comment: @Shrikant Suresh Lahase: If this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is of course no obligation to do this.